# Which electrical circuit produces a decaying alternating current wave in response to a pulse?

Tags: passive-filter

Consider a voltage source with an infinitesimally short burst having voltage time-integral 1.

I see how a low-pass filter creates an output voltage like \$e^{-kt}\$ for some \$k\in\mathbb R\$.  What if \$k\$ were complex?  Which circuit produces a decaying alternating current in response to a pulse?

Illustrated below are the results of five evenly-spaced pulses.  The blue graph shows the output of a regular low-pass filter.  The orange graph (with \$k\$ that happens to have exactly the same frequency as the input pulses) is what I'm trying to produce.[image]

---

Here's a diagram of what I think is being suggested in the comments:
[image]

Comment: Several simple R/L/C configurations, e.g. series R/L/C with the output taken across C, giving the second order transfer function:\$\frac{1}{s^2LC+sCR+1}\$. The resistance value needs to be relatively small to ensure the arrangement is underdamped. The frequency of the oscillations is approximately \$\frac{1}{\sqr{LC}}

Comment: Any kind of resonant filter will do this. High-quality inductor in series with a high-quality capacitor (both having low resistance) will do it. (Don't add additional resistance if you can help it, if you want long ringing.) This ends up being filters with high Q. In the digital domain, a FIR filter that's long enough, or a IIR filter with high Q, will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also examine a resonant circuit with Fresonate at 1/2 the pulse frequency.
And slightly vary the pulse frequency. You'll see the effects of energy building and cancelling within the same period of ringing.

By the way, this really occurs. The phenomena brings up the question of "What are harmonics?"

For those without SPICE, or not wanting to learn SPICE, the tool Signal Wave Explorer SWE is available for free download. There are 14 canned examples, with only 3 mouse clicks to select and run. Then you can edit params, to place the pulse frequency exactly at Fresonate, or at 1/2 Fresonate. And rerun.

The tool uses Fourier Analysis (behind the scenes) to compute the output waveform, given input waveform and circuit frequency/phase response. 
By default, you'll see input waveform, input spectrum, circuit spectrum, output spectrum and output waveform.

Here are 120MHz impulses into a 300MHz resonator, Q=10
[image]